# ES6/typescript how to create an array with key and value?

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular6

I have a simple question.
I'd like to create an Array with ['Key'=value] in Angular ES6/Typescript.
I need to put the data like this:

```
> Revenues = [ Product: "myProduct 1", Revenue: 1234.56 ],
>            [ Product: "myProduct 2", Revenue: 5678.90 ]
```

I need to iterate this, sumarize them, sort them, take keys separately in some situations and values separately in others, etc.

Something similar in PHP to `$revenue[] = [ 'product' => value ];`

Is it possible? How can a make it?

Could someone post an example?

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for an **object**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can code like this:

```js
revenues=[
  {
    Product: "myProduct 1", 
    Revenue: 1234.56 
  },
  {
    Product: "myProduct 2", 
    Revenue: 5678.90
  }
]

revenues.forEach((item)=>{
   // your code
    console.log(item.Product);
    console.log(item.Revenue);
})
```

Comment: Since the OP seems to be new to JavaScript, please explain your code and ideally add links to further reading material.

Comment: Felix, indeed, newbie totally. Thanks so much for your answer. I'll try this.

Comment: just another contribution, please: Supose I need to fill this array with data caming from a loop. I have a for (let i=0;i<oservable_response.length;i++ ) {....} I need to put data from this observable_response. Is revenue[] = { product: observable_response[i].ProductiId, revenue: observable_response[i].revenue}? is it?